# EF Core multiple DbContexts for one database

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm going to separate `DbContext` as a individual project and share the `DbContext` with two projects.

Now assume I have:

**Project.Data**

```
namespace Project.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options) { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            public DbSet<Bar> Bars{ get; set; }
            public DbSet<Foo> Foos{ get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

And I need a different `DbContext` model for my desktop client and web app. Say, something like this:

**Project.Client** (use the base context)

```
namespace Project.Client
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : Project.Core.ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

**Project.Web** (use some additional `DbSet`s)

```
namespace Project.Web
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : Project.Core.ApplicationDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) 
        { }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);

            public DbSet<Hoge> Hoges{ get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here my concern is that even if it works, once migration happens in the context of `Project.Client`, the table `Hoges` is removed because there's no corresponding `DbSet` in the `DbContext`.

Is this approach feasible, or do I need to go another way? One solution I think is to include all `DbSet`s in `Project.Data` and let the two applications to use the `DbContext` as it is, but I don't like to do it.

Comment: Why do you think the table would be removed?

Comment: Migration compares the database and DbContext model and modify the database when the structure is different, assuming always the DbContext is right. Hence if I run `dotnet ef migrations add brahbrah` with dotnet CLI in Project.Client it will make DROP TABLE query to update the database to match to the model of Project.Client. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: Migrations don't really look at the database, they look at your code. You would be better off just trying this out to see what happens.

Comment: This could work, but I wouldn't recommend this approach, as it becomes rather painful to manage when you have two separate sets of migrations: the migrations needed for the base context, and the migrations needed for the derived context. You'll start to see the `The model backing the data context has changed` exception message a lot.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah I misunderstood. Then it may work I'd like to try another way. Please see the next comment.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson So if I really want to have separate context model for the two applications, it's more appropriate to have two "databases", and let them have a common DbContext and only Project.Web have the second DbContext, is that right?

Comment: You could take that approach, that also has the downside of not being able to enforce foreign keys from a table in the web context to a table in the common context. I can think of another alternative, but before I suggest it, are these two contexts accessing the same database? Or is the web application accessing a global database, and each desktop client accessing a local database?

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson I think about the case where both desktop client and web app will access to the same database (on Azure SQL), since the common dbcontext contains ApplicationUser class for authentication.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend _DON'T DO THAT_! Speaking from personal experience, having two separate applications access the same database introduces coupling. You can't update the database structure for the web application, if there are still desktop applications using the old structure, and vice versa. That's when you _really_ start getting hammered by the `The model backing the data context has changed` exception message. Instead, I'd recommend having the web application expose an API, and the desktop application access the data through an API instead of directly through the database

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Well, so the suggestion is to get rid of anything about database from desktop client, and let it to communicate with the database through API, right? Then I think I don't need to create Project.Data and I can keep everything in Project.Web.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Also, another solution I came up with is that to let the client communicate with Azure Functions, and then the function would send queries to the database. I thought it will reduce the number of simultaneous connection to the database, but the problem you mentioned would not be solved *unless* I also make the web app to communicate all what it needs via the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164929/discussion-between-andrew-williamson-and-k-makino).

Comment: Here's a cheap idea. Partial classes. Put those dbsets in their own file. That way project one can only have whst it needs, project two what it needs and project three everything. Then just use project three for migrations. Works for me. No need to hack any code it just takes a bit more time while creating the initial projects and linking the files from the third project to the other two :)